# Android アプリで初回設定画面を作りたい

Tags: java, android

現在のソースコードでは毎回アプリ起動時にhomeとschoolの値を入力するようになっていますが、この入力を初回起動時のみにし、それ以降は初回に入力したhomeとschoolの値を使用したいです。

MainActivity.java (初回のみ表示したい)

```
package com.websarva.wings.android.testsample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String preName = "MAIN_SETTING";
    private final String dataIntPreTag ="dataIPT";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    private int dataInt;
    public static EditText hometext;
    public static EditText schooltext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());
    }

    private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hometext = findViewById(R.id.home);
            schooltext = findViewById(R.id.school);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("home", hometext.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("school", schooltext.getText().toString());


            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="自宅"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.215"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="学校"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.214"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.301" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/school"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="登録"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/school"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

NewActivity.java

```
package com.websarva.wings.android.testsample;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.AppLaunchChecker;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static String home;
    public static String school;
    private GetLatLng getLL;
    private WeatherTask wt;
    //private MapsActivity map;
    private TextView homeIcon, schoolIcon, kasaInfo, homeDate, schoolDate, homeWeatherIcon, schoolWeatherIcon, homeWeatherTemp, schoolWeatherTemp;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker Home;
    MapFragment mf;
    static double latitude;
    static double longitude;
    static double homelat,homelng,schoollat,schoollng;
    static int rain=0;
    private Context context;
    public static String homeMarker,schoolMarker;
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor edit;


    public NewActivity(){
        this.latch = latch;
    }


    @SuppressLint({"StaticFieldLeak", "SetTextI18n", "CommitPrefEdits"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(AppLaunchChecker.hasStartedFromLauncher(this)){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

            Intent intent = this.getIntent();
            home = intent.getStringExtra("home");
            school = intent.getStringExtra("school");

            homeIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_icon);
            kasaInfo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.kasa_info);
            schoolIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.school_icon);
            homeWeatherIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_weather_icon);
            schoolWeatherIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.school_weather_icon);
            homeWeatherTemp = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_weather_Temp);
            schoolWeatherTemp = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.school_weather_Temp);

            homeIcon.setText(home);
            schoolIcon.setText(school);


            //日時
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int hh = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

            homeDate = findViewById(R.id.home_date);
            schoolDate = findViewById(R.id.school_date);

            if(hh>0 && hh<=3){
                homeDate.setText("  3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>3 && hh<=6){
                homeDate.setText("  6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時"  );
                schoolDate.setText("  6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>6 && hh<=9){
                homeDate.setText("  9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>9 && hh<=12){
                homeDate.setText("  12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時"  );
                schoolDate.setText("  12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>12 && hh<=15){
                homeDate.setText("  15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>15 && hh<=18){
                homeDate.setText("  18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>18 && hh<=21){
                homeDate.setText("  21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>21){
                homeDate.setText("  24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時  ");
            }


            try{
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addressList = gcd.getFromLocationName(home, 1);
                Address address = addressList.get(0);

                latitude = address.getLatitude();
                longitude = address.getLongitude();


            }catch(IOException e){
            }

            homelat = latitude;
            homelng = longitude;

            wt = new WeatherTask();
            wt.setListener(homeCreateListener());
            wt.onPostExecute("");

            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addressList = gcd.getFromLocationName(school, 1);
                Address address = addressList.get(0);

                latitude = address.getLatitude();
                longitude = address.getLongitude();


            }catch(IOException e){
            }

            schoollat = latitude;
            schoollng = longitude;

            wt = new WeatherTask();
            wt.setListener(schoolCreateListener());
            wt.execute("");
            //countDownLatch.countDown();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            edit.putBoolean("Launched",true);
            edit.commit();
        }
        else {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

            Intent intent = this.getIntent();
            home = intent.getStringExtra("home");
            school = intent.getStringExtra("school");

            homeIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_icon);
            kasaInfo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.kasa_info);
            schoolIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.school_icon);
            homeWeatherIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_weather_icon);
            schoolWeatherIcon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.school_weather_icon);
            homeWeatherTemp = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.home_weather_Temp);
            schoolWeatherTemp = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.school_weather_Temp);

            homeIcon.setText(home);
            schoolIcon.setText(school);

            //日時
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int hh = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

            homeDate = findViewById(R.id.home_date);
            schoolDate = findViewById(R.id.school_date);

            if(hh>0 && hh<=3){
                homeDate.setText("  3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>3 && hh<=6){
                homeDate.setText("  6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時"  );
                schoolDate.setText("  6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>6 && hh<=9){
                homeDate.setText("  9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  9時   12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>9 && hh<=12){
                homeDate.setText("  12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時"  );
                schoolDate.setText("  12時   15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>12 && hh<=15){
                homeDate.setText("  15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  15時   18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>15 && hh<=18){
                homeDate.setText("  18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  18時   21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>18 && hh<=21){
                homeDate.setText("  21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  21時   24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時  ");
            }
            else if(hh>21){
                homeDate.setText("  24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時  ");
                schoolDate.setText("  24時   3時   6時   9時   12時   15時   18時   21時  ");
            }


            try{
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addressList = gcd.getFromLocationName(home, 1);
                Address address = addressList.get(0);

                latitude = address.getLatitude();
                longitude = address.getLongitude();


            }catch(IOException e){
            }

            homelat = latitude;
            homelng = longitude;

            wt = new WeatherTask();
            wt.setListener(homeCreateListener());
            wt.onPostExecute("");

            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addressList = gcd.getFromLocationName(school, 1);
                Address address = addressList.get(0);

                latitude = address.getLatitude();
                longitude = address.getLongitude();


            }catch(IOException e){
            }

            schoollat = latitude;
            schoollng = longitude;

            wt = new WeatherTask();
            wt.setListener(schoolCreateListener());
            wt.execute("");
            //countDownLatch.countDown();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }
        AppLaunchChecker.onActivityCreate(this);
    }

    private WeatherTask.Listener homeCreateListener() {
        return new WeatherTask.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String count) {
                String[] res = count.split(",", 0);
                latch.countDown();
                String currentTemp = "";
                String minTemp = "";
                String maxTemp = "";
                String iconId = "";
                iconId += " ";
                for (int i = 0; i < res.length/3; i++) {

                    currentTemp += "  "+(res[i*3])+"    ";
                    iconId += "   "+(res[i*3+1])+"  ";
                    if(res[i*3+1].equals("☔")){
                        rain+=1;
                    }
                }
                homeWeatherIcon.setText(iconId);
                homeWeatherTemp.setText(currentTemp);
                homeMarker = iconId;
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

    }
    private WeatherTask.Listener schoolCreateListener() {
        return new WeatherTask.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String count) {
                String[] res = count.split(",", 0);
                latch.countDown();

                String currentTemp="";
                String minTemp="";
                String maxTemp="";
                String iconId="";
                iconId += " ";
                for(int i=0;i<res.length/3;i++){

                    currentTemp +="    "+(res[i*3])+"   ";
                    iconId += "   "+(res[i*3+1])+"   ";
                    if(res[i*3+1].equals("☔")){
                        rain+=1;
                    }
                }
                schoolWeatherIcon.setText(iconId);
                schoolWeatherTemp.setText(currentTemp);

                schoolMarker = iconId;

                if(rain==0){
                    kasaInfo.setText("今日はいい天気！傘はいらない！");
                }
                else if(rain<4){
                    kasaInfo.setText("折り畳み傘があると安心！");
                }
                else{
                    kasaInfo.setText("雨傘をもっていこう");
                }
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private GetLatLng.Listener getlatlng() {
        return new GetLatLng.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String count) {
                String[] res = count.split(",", 0);
                latitude = Double.parseDouble(res[0]);
                longitude = Double.parseDouble(res[1]);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng home = new LatLng(homelat, homelng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title(homeMarker).snippet(homeMarker).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        LatLng school = new LatLng(schoollat, schoollng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(school).title(schoolMarker).snippet(schoolMarker));
        LatLng center = new LatLng(homelat+(homelat+schoollat)/2,homelng+(homelng+schoollng)/2);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(center));
        zoomMap(homelat,homelng,schoollat,schoollng);
    }
    private void zoomMap(double homelat, double homelon, double schoollat, double schoollon){
        double south,west,north,east;
        if(homelat > schoollat){
            south = homelat - 0.8;
            north = schoollat + 0.8;
        }else{
            south = schoollat - 0.8;
            north = homelat + 0.8;
        }

        if(homelon > schoollon){
            west = schoollon - 0.8;
            east = homelon +0.8;
        }
        else{
            west = homelon - 0.8;
            east = schoollon + 0.8;
        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
                .include(new LatLng(south , west))
                .include(new LatLng(north, east))
                .build();

        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
                newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, 0));

    }

}
```

activity_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="476dp"
        android:layout_height="293dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="293dp"
        app:cameraZoom="8.0"
        tools:content="@id/mapView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kasa_info"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#e6e6fa"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.54"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/school_icon"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_style"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_icon"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_style"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/kasa_info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/school_weather_Temp"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        style="@style/list"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/school_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/school_weather_icon" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/school_weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        style="@style/list"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/school_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/school_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/school_date"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        style="@style/list"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/school_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_weather_Temp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_weather_Temp"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        style="@style/list"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/home_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_weather_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_date"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        style="@style/list"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/home_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/kasa_info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        style="@style/list"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_style"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/home_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_date" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: やりたいことに対して、今現在はどのような動きになるのでしょうか？

Comment: やりたいことは、MainActivityを呼び出すのは初回起動時のみで次回からは起動すればNewActivityが起動し、初回起動時に入力したhomeとschoolを使用したいです。

Comment: 現在の動きは、起動時に毎回MainActivityが呼び出されます。

Answer (score 0):

初期画面をactivity_new.xmlにして、homeとschoolを入力したらデータベースに格納する形にすることで解決しました。